# How Can i filter a cut function?

Tags: r

Maybe i dont have to use cut but i can not find any other method
What i am trying to do is, on this table

```
y2018<- matrix(c(7.8,5,9,4,2.3,4,6),ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(y2018) <- c("Numb")
```

i want to add a column so it will be like this

```
y2018$d_grade <- cut(y2018$Numb, c(-Inf,4.9,6.25,7.5,8.75,10), labels = c('Failed', 'Medium', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Excellent'))
```

but I want to write failed where lower than 5 and then automatically cut the rest numbers, i dont want to write `c(-Inf,4.9,6.25,7.5,8.75,10)` 
i dont know if its possible

something like this

```
y2018$d_grade <- cut(y2018$Numb, 5, labels = c('Failed', 'Medium', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Excellent'))
```

Thanks Anyways

Comment: please add your data and desired results into the question as "copy&paste" code (not linked images).  Have a read of this excellent guidance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Firstly, you have to understand the nature of `matrix`, that must contain all value with same types.
- Therefore, you should start your data as `dataframe` or `tibble`

```
y2018<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(7.8,5,9,4,2.3,4,6),ncol=1,byrow=TRUE))
colnames(y2018) <- c("Numb")

  Numb
1  7.8
2  5.0
3  9.0
4  4.0
5  2.3
6  4.0
7  6.0
```

Then, if you want to add data, use `cbind` or dplyr `mutate`

```
d_grade <- cut(y2018$Numb, c(-Inf,4.9,6.25,7.5,8.75,10), 
                  labels = c('Failed', 'Medium', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Excellent'))
cbind(y2018, d_grade)

  Numb   d_grade
1  7.8 Very Good
2  5.0    Medium
3  9.0 Excellent
4  4.0    Failed
5  2.3    Failed
6  4.0    Failed
7  6.0    Medium
```

There are other way than using cut such as dplyr `mutate` + `case_when` check the documentation further.